# Python Pandas Web Scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, select

I'm trying to turn a list of tables on this page into a Pandas DataFrame:
https://intermediaries.hsbc.co.uk/products/product-finder/

I want to select the customer type box only and select one of the elements (from first to last) and then click find product to display the table for each one before concatenating all the DataFrames into 1 DataFrame.

So far I have managed to select the first element and print the table but I can't seem to turn it into a pandas DataFrame as I get a value error: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 38, 12)

This is my code:

```
def product_type_button(self):
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id('Availability'))
    try:
        select.select_by_visible_text('First time buyer')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('The item does not exist')
    time.sleep(5)
    
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button" and (contains(text(),"Find product"))]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

def create_dataframe(self):

    data1 = pd.read_html(self.driver.page_source)
    print(data1)

    data2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    time.sleep(5)

    data2.to_csv('Data1.csv')
```

I would like to find a way to print the table for each element, maybe selecting by index instead? and then concatenating into one DataFrame. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data for the table is located inside javascript file. You can use `re`/`json` to parse it and then construct the dataframe:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


js_src = "https://intermediaries.hsbc.co.uk/component---src-pages-products-product-finder-js-9c7004fb8446c3fe0a07.js"
data = requests.get(js_src).text

data = re.search(r"JSON\.parse\('(.*)'\)", data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

| Changed | NewProductCode | PreviousProductCode | ProductType | Deal Period (Fixed until) | ProductDescription1 | ProductTerm | Availability | Repayment Basis | Min LTV % | MaxLTV | Minimum Loan ? | Fees Payable Per | Rate | Reversionary Rate % | APR | BookingFee | Cashback | CashbackValue | ERC - Payable | Unlimited lump sum payments Premitted (without fees) | Unlimited overpayment permitted (without fees) | Overpayments | ERC | Portable | Completionfee | Free Legals for Remortgage | FreeStandardValuation | Loading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Continued | 4071976 |  | Fixed | 31.03.25 | Fee Saver* | 2 Year Fixed | FTB | CR and IO | 0% | 60% | 10,000 | 5,000,000 | 5.99% | 5.04% | 5.4 | 0 | No | 0 | Yes | No | No | Yes | Please refer to HSBC policy guide | Yes | 17 | Yes | Yes | nan |
| Continued | 4071977 |  | Fixed | 31.03.25 | Fee Saver* | 2 Year Fixed | FTB | CR and IO | 0% | 70% | 10,000 | 2,000,000 | 6.04% | 5.04% | 5.4 | 0 | No | 0 | Yes | No | No | Yes | Please refer to HSBC policy guide | Yes | 17 | Yes | Yes | nan |
| Continued | 4071978 |  | Fixed | 31.03.25 | Fee Saver* | 2 Year Fixed | FTB | CR and IO | 0% | 75% | 10,000 | 2,000,000 | 6.04% | 5.04% | 5.4 | 0 | No | 0 | Yes | No | No | Yes | Please refer to HSBC policy guide | Yes | 17 | Yes | Yes | nan |
| Continued | 4071979 |  | Fixed | 31.03.25 | Fee Saver* | 2 Year Fixed | FTB | CR | 0% | 80% | 10,000 | 1,000,000 | 6.14% | 5.04% | 5.4 | 0 | No | 0 | Yes | No | No | Yes | Please refer to HSBC policy guide | Yes | 17 | Yes | Yes | nan |
| Continued | 4071980 |  | Fixed | 31.03.25 | Fee Saver* | 2 Year Fixed | FTB | CR | 0% | 85% | 10,000 | 750,000 | 6.19% | 5.04% | 5.4 | 0 | No | 0 | Yes | No | No | Yes | Please refer to HSBC policy guide | Yes | 17 | Yes | Yes | nan |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: You are a legend! Thank You! I only hope I can become this good at finding solutions one day. +1

Comment: Hi, this seems to be failing now with an error of 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'? Also is there a more robust way to find the json file automatically in case the name space changes?

Comment: @user19795989 Seems the page is changing the name of the javascript file, now it's something like `https://intermediaries.hsbc.co.uk/component---src-pages-products-product-finder-js-1cdc6933728e418b5106.js`. More robust way is to load https://intermediaries.hsbc.co.uk/products/product-finder/ into a soup, find the javascript filename and then use that file.

Comment: Hey @Andrej not sure how to tag you, but would be awesome if you could help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483599/python-pandas-pdf-web-scrape :)

Answer (score 1):

A minimal change to your code: [pd.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a *list* of dataframes for all tables found on the webpage.

Since there is only one table on your page, `data1` is a list of 1 dataframe. This is where the error `Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 38, 12)` comes from – `data1` contains 1 dataframe of shape (38, 12).

You probably want to do just:

```
data2 = data1[0]
data2.to_csv(...)
```

(Also, no need to sleep after reading from the webpage)

Comment: Thank You very much, this did the trick. :) +1
I was adding the sleep just incase it took time for any additional data to load, but I guess I didn't need it